# Novella (and follow up short story) in Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine about the stars going out. Published ~20 years ago

Tags: story-identification, novella, apocalypse

I am trying to find a novella (and its follow up short story) that were published in "Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine" on the order of 20 years ago (+/- 5 years).

Premise: for reasons unknown, in contemporary times all the stars in the universe have gone out. The novella covers the whole thing, from the discovery past the end of the universe (it's complicated). The short story was more focused, was set before Earth's atmosphere had condensed to liquid. It made fun of CNN journalist Wolf Blitzer's name. Also, the Russians bombed their own rioting people in Moscow, and back in the US, there were neighbors mobbing the protagonists towards the end.

Comment: Were they going out without any fuss?

Comment: @MrLister the novella wouldn't have "covered the whole thing".

Comment: longshot, maybe wrong period, doesn't look like it was in IASFM, but: [Last Contact](http://zestfullyblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/last-contact-by-stephen-baxter-part-1.html) by Stephen Baxter?

Comment: @MrLister the rest of it doesn't sound anything like that story

Comment: @MrLister In the short story the Russians bombed their own rioting people in Moscow, and back in the US their were neighbors mobbing the protagonists towards the end.

Comment: Maybe a followup to William Hope Hodgson's _The Night Land_? There were a few of those. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night_Land#Pastiche,_homages_and_sequels)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer It wasn't. But that does look interesting.

Comment: There is an Arthur C. Clarke short story "The Nine Billion Names of God" (1953) which is quite famous, but was first published decades before the indicated period.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Billion_Names_of_God

Comment: 'The last question' is one where the Stars die out, along with all matter and energy. But there's no mention of liquid nitrogen in there.

Comment: The stars going out unexpectedly has some similarities to the Xeelee Sequence by Baxter...

Comment: @A. Golding it might be worth posting that as an answer, further in that wiki page it states that the story won the Hugo award for best short story of 1954 in 2004, I imagine this would have led to reprints etc and would match up with the questions idea of 20 years + or - 4-5 years.

Comment: @RichardC No, it is most definitely a contemporary story set in modern (turn of the millennium) times. As mentioned, they make fun of Wolf Blitzer's name, in reference to his work as a CNN journalist. Furthermore, IASFM (or now "Asimov's Science Fiction") only very, very rarely does reprints. Thanks for the suggestion, however.

Comment: I have found them! The stories are William Barton's "Moments of Inertia" (Asimov's April/May 2004) and the sequel "Dark of the Sun" (Asimov's April/May 2005).

Comment: @ThomasHoltz Then please post that as an answer and accept your own answer (clicking the check mark on the left),  so that this is removed from the "Unanswered" list.

Comment: @JacobC.saysReinstateMonica Thanks. I have done so. (This is my first encounter with the site, so I didn't know all the operations.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found them! The stories are William Barton's "[Moments of Inertia](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13537458-moments-of-inertia)" (Asimov's April/May 2004) and the sequel "[Dark of the Sun](http://sfrevu.com/Review-id.php?id=2705)" (Asimov's April/May 2005)

> What will you do when the Sun goes out? That’s the question two fifty somethings, living out the bitter endgame of their wasted lives, must answer. It’s the end of the world, not just as they know it, but for real. Paul and Scott have been the best of friends since childhood, ever since they checked the same book out of their elementary school library, but they’ve come to loath one another, as life’s catastrophes slowly beat them down. Now, a real catastrophe will kill them, and everyone else in the world, unless they find a way to survive. The answer they come up with is utterly heroic. And it will make or break them as men.

....

> "Dark of the Sun" by William Barton is a follow-up to his previous story, "Moments of Inertia" in April/May 2004 issue. Again, four people are coping with the extinction of the Sun.

Comment: Congrats! Can you provide some summary for the stories to increase the chance of other people finding them?